# Keep formatting of Excel file when loading into DataFrame in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to load a Excel file into Python and keep the formatting of the   columns/ data. I have numbers which are stored as text, but Python changes the formatting to numbers which causes an issues as it only shows 15 significant digits in a number, and changes digits after the 15th place to 0 (as it would do in Excel). I would like to keep the numbers as Text to have all digits.

I'm using:

```
myContractData = pd.read_excel(Path)
```

Thanks a lot a lot for your help.
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you case is based on loading data to a excel file, you need to ensure the number in the excel files has 15+ digits.

what I know in old office versions, excel only handle 15 significant digits of precision  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113
if you use Excel load the number, the number is rounded to 15 digits automatically. That’s why in Excel files for numbers, we can only see the 15 digits of the value.

if possible, I would suggest you connecting to the data source directly in Python, or convert it to string in data source.